# Dependency Injection with Ignite & Guice

Tags: android, guice, javafxports

I currently try to get a simple JavaFXMobile application to run, but I tripped over the DI on Android, while the Desktop is working as expected.

I got the following exception (note especially the last line, indicating, that we try to access the wrong kind of class files...):

```
11-02 17:09:08.152: W/System.err(28254): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$138(LauncherImpl.java:182)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254):    ... 1 more
11-02 17:09:08.153: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:136)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:547)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at eu.dzim.test.ui.fxml.FXMLLoaderServiceGuice.controllerForClass(FXMLLoaderServiceGuice.java:98)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at eu.dzim.test.ui.fxml.FXMLLoaderServiceGuice.access$lambda$1(FXMLLoaderServiceGuice.java)
11-02 17:09:08.154: W/System.err(28254):    at eu.dzim.test.ui.fxml.FXMLLoaderServiceGuice$$Lambda$2.call(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:929)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at eu.dzim.test.Main.start(Main.java:60)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(LauncherImpl.java)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(PlatformImpl.java)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)
11-02 17:09:08.155: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
11-02 17:09:08.156: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
11-02 17:09:08.156: W/System.err(28254):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
11-02 17:09:08.156: W/System.err(28254):    ... 1 more
11-02 17:09:08.156: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:25)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
11-02 17:09:08.158: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254):    ... 44 more
11-02 17:09:08.159: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:22)
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254):    ... 63 more
11-02 17:09:08.160: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-02 17:09:08.166: W/System.err(28254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 17:09:08.166: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
11-02 17:09:08.166: W/System.err(28254):    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
11-02 17:09:08.166: W/System.err(28254):    ... 68 more
11-02 17:09:08.166: W/System.err(28254): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
11-02 17:09:08.167: W/System.err(28254):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
11-02 17:09:08.167: W/System.err(28254):    ... 71 more
```

My dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.1'
    compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12'
    compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4'

    compile 'com.gluonhq:ignite-guice:1.0.0'
}
```

What I found curious is, that I was able to instantiate the class `eu.dzim.test.ui.fxml.FXMLLoaderServiceGuice` via the `com.google.inject.Injector` instance. But my `FXMLLoaderService` is not able to do so, due to the exception above...

Does anyone have experience with this? Otherwise I will try switch to the more simplistic approach of Afterburner.fx injection (but without his presentation stuff - but don't beat me for this ;-) ).

Thanks and regards,
Daniel

PS: If you need more info, just ask and I will comment and/or update the question accordingly...

Comment: You use Guice in an Android project? If you want to use Guice, maybe you should have a look at Roboguice 4.0. Or, if you want to use dependency injection on Android, have a look at Toothpick (https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick)

Comment: Yeah. On Android. The point is, Gluon (they build and provide the JavaFXMobile stuff) have the Ignite sub-project, which allows Guice-, Spring- and Dagger-1-DI. I thought (a.k.a. hoped), that they have been able to work around Guice's limitations... :-)

Comment: Roboguice does that, but version 3.0 on their site is deprecated and version 4.0 is hard to find. I recommend ToothPick, by one of the former Roboguice developers. Easier to use than Dagger, imho.

Comment: Have you tried with  the latest version of `Ignite`? `1.0.1`?

Comment: @Christine I wanted to use ONE framework for all plattforms. So no, I did not test RoboGuice (which I was aware of, but not that there is a v4). And you are right - I find Dagger (v1) hard to set up...

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov I was not aware of this version. I tried it with 1.0.0... I've now set up Afterburner and use its injection mechanism and so far it's ok. But I'd prefer Guice. Is it even possible to use Iginte's Guice on Android (I didn't find any clues in the sources...)

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov Am I correct, that I could try the new version with the repository https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/ ?

Comment: Once again: @EugeneRyzhikov v1.0.1 did not change anything. If you try to use Guice, it will fail on Android with the aforementioned error. What a pitty! :-/